# How to show percentage up to the current observation?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the following data frame:

[image]

I am wondering how I can create a new column which shows the percentage of the indicator column for all previous observations within the group. So the above data frame would become:

[image]

Basically, the new column just indicates the percentage (in decimal form) of the indicator up to that point within the group. It just divides the sum of the indicator column up to that point by the row count of previous observations within the group.

My first thought was to use `group_by` along with `row_number` in order reference previous observations, but I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Data:

```
structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Indicator = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), IndicatorPercent = c(NA, 
1, 0.5, 0.67, 0.75, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.25)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We get the `cummean` of the 'Indicator' after grouping by 'Group' and then get the `lag` on it

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(IndicatorPercent = lag(cummean(Indicator))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   Group Indicator IndicatorPercent
#   <int>     <int>            <dbl>
# 1     1         1           NA    
# 2     1         0            1    
# 3     1         1            0.5  
# 4     1         1            0.667
# 5     1         0            0.75 
# 6     2         0           NA    
# 7     2         0            0    
# 8     2         0            0    
# 9     2         1            0    
#10     2         0            0.25
```

---

If we want to do this based on value of other column, use `replace`

```
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(IndicatorPercent = replace(rep(NA_real_, n()),
      color == 'red', lag(cummean(Indicator[color == "red"])))) %>%
    fill(IndicatorPercent) %>%
    ungroup
```

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[color == 'red', 
   IndicatorPercent := shift(cummean(Indicator)), Group][, 
   IndicatorPercent := nafill(IndicatorPercent, type = 'locf'), Group][]
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this for only variables with a certain value in another column? Suppose I had a third column called color, and wanted to do exactly as above, but only for observations where color == 'red'. I tried doing this by adding in square brackets to your solution ```mutate(IndicatorPercent = lag(cummean(Indicator [color == "red"])))``` to no avail. Is there another way of accomplishing this?

Comment: @rogues77 I think it is more convenient in `data.table`.  `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[color == 'red', IndicatorPercent := shift(cummean(Indicator)), Group]`

Comment: @rogues77 with tidyverse, option is `mutate(IndicatorPercent = replace(rep(NA_real_, n()), color == 'red', lag(cummean(Indicator [color == "red"])))`

Comment: is there any way to fill in the NA values that are generated with the previous non-NA observation? Your tidyverse solution works, but it leaves a lot of NA values--can I just replace those somehow with the previous numeric value generated in the above code?

Comment: @rogues77 that is easy. You can do `%>% fill(IndicatorPercent)` after the group_by

Comment: You're amazing. Thank you.